# Insert a Control in UserControl

Tags: wpf, user-controls, flash

I have a `UserControl` to load swf, it works fine. but when I add a Button Control in it, it doesn't show my swf.

here is my code that use my `UserControl`( FlashPlayer is my `UserControl` ) :

```
<Window x:Class="FlashTest.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:FlashPlayerLibrary;assembly=FlashPlayerLibrary"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="768" Width="1024">
<Grid>
    <controls:FlashPlayer Source="E:\\Lesson1.swf" Width="1024" Height="768">
        <Button Width="20" Height="20" ></Button></controls:FlashPlayer>
</Grid>
```

is there anyway to insert Control in `UserControl`.

Comment: This dependes on the way the usercontrol handles child content. Have a look there.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to put a Button over it and not in it. 
You are using a Grid so you can try something like this:

```
<Grid>
    <controls:FlashPlayer Source="E:\\Lesson1.swf" Width="1024" Height="768">
    </controls:FlashPlayer>
    <Button Width="20" Height="20"></Button>
</Grid>
```

It should work if the FlashPlayer control doesn't do something too strange.